# Writing R functions to support vectors

Tags: r, function, vector

I have this function:

```
pcal.getPeriodForDate <- function(date_) {
    dateObject <- as.POSIXlt(date_)
    calendarStart <- pcal.getCalendarStart(dateObject$year + 1900)

    difference <- dateObject - calendarStart

    if(difference < 0) {
        calendarStart <- pcal.getCalendarStart(dateObject$year + 1899)
        difference <- dateObject - calendarStart
    }

    period <- difference / 28

    week <- ifelse(period < 1, ceiling(period * 4), ceiling((period - floor(period)) * 4))

    return(list(Period = as.numeric(ceiling(period)), Week = week))
}
```

I also have a data frame  with the following structure

```
> str(sells)
'data.frame':   73738 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ LOC_NBR: chr  "2" "2" "2" "2" ...
 $ SLS_DT : Date, format: "2015-02-01" "2015-02-02" "2015-02-03" "2015-02-04" ...
 $ SALES  : num  1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
sells$pd <- pcal.getPeriodForDate(sells$SLS_DT)$Period
```

however, i get a ton of warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (year < 2000) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In seedYear:year :
  numerical expression has 73738 elements: only the first used
3: In if (difference < 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (year < 2000) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In seedYear:year :
  numerical expression has 73738 elements: only the first used
```

the function works fine passing one value:

```
> pcal.getPeriodForDate('2015-09-29')
$Period
[1] 9

$Week
[1] 3
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: `could not find function "pcal.getCalendarStart"`

Comment: easiest/quickest way is to vectorize the function `v <- Vectorize(pcal.getPeriodForDate)` and `v(sells$SLS_DT)`

Answer (score 2):

The function `if` is not vectorized in R which means that you can only use it with vectors of length 1. Using `if` with bigger vectors will cause the warnings you get which is a very serious warning that should not be ignored as `if` only uses the first element of the vector which will most likely cause you trouble. See this simple case:

```
> if(c(1,-5,3) > 0) print('hello')
[1] "hello"
Warning message:
In if (c(1, -5, 3) > 0) print("hello") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

In this case although there is a `-5` in the vector above `hello` is returned only because `if` checks the first element of the vector.

In order to use `if` with a vector you have three options:

#### all

Use it with function `all` when you want every element of the vector to confirm the condition:

```
if( all(c(1,-5,3) > 0) ) print('hello')
#this does not return anything
```

#### any

Use it with function `any` when you want at least one of the elements to confirm the condition:

```
> if( any(c(1,-5,3) > 0) ) print('hello')
[1] "hello"
```

#### apply family

Use it with the *apply family when you need a vector same size as the one in check (`c(1,-5,3)` here) where each element will be checked against the condition:

```
> vapply(c(1,-5,3), function(x) {
   if (x > 0) 'Hello' else NA_character_
 }, 
 character(1))
[1] "Hello" NA      "Hello"
```

I cannot run your function to tell you which version of the above you need as I do not know how `difference` is used or what `pcal.getCalendarStart` does but this should be enough to help you fix the warnings you get. Use one of the above according to how you want if to behave and you should get no warnings.

Comment: Sorry about that. The other functions are written in the same manner, i.e. not vectorized. I did Vectorize on the function and that gave me the results I needed.